# How to prove the following for inner product and positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

In the solution of problem 2.10(b) of Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*, it is mentioned that if

$$g^Tv = 0, \qquad v^TAv \geq 0 \qquad \forall v$$

where $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $g$ is a vector with real elements), then there must exist $\lambda$ such that $A+\lambda gg^T$ is positive semidefinite. How to obtain this?

Here is the solution image which I am talking about:

---

[image]

---

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is given here? $A$ and $g$? What about $v$? For all $v$? etc.

Comment: If $g^T v=0$ for all $v$ then $g=0$.

Comment: @NicNic8 no $g^Tv$ is not zero for all $v$ but $v^TAv\geq 0$ for all $v$

Comment: @FrankMoses: If $v^T A v \geq 0$ for all $v$ then you can choose $\lambda =0$ (as $A$ is already semidefinite).

Comment: @Fabian can you please explain why I cannot chose any value I like because $g^Tv=0$?

Comment: @Fabian I have added the solution image. This may have clarified my question. I want to how does 2.10.A results in the last equation in the image. I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

From what's given, $A$ is positive semidefinite.  Therefore,

\begin{align}
  v^T (A + \lambda g g^T ) v &= v^T A v + \lambda v^T g g^T v \\
    &= v^T A v + \lambda (v^T g)(g^Tv) \\
    &= v^T A v + 0 \\
    &= v^T A v \\
    &\geq 0.
\end{align}